# Why is my output disregarding every other sample and why is the frequency half of the expected value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wav, waveform

I'm playing with [Python's wave module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html), and I have run into two issues that I can't figure out.

1. Every other sample has an amplitude of 0. The desired behavior is to have a continuous sinusoidal wave.
2. The produced frequency seems to be half of the desired frequency. Looking at the math, I can't figure why. I understand how to fix it. I just can't figure out the reasoning. In my mind, multiplying the frequency by 2π, not 4π, makes sense to me.

   ```
   from functools import partial, wraps
   from math import pi, sin
   import struct
   import wave

   class Wave:
       def __init__(self, frequency, amplitude=1.0, phase_shift=0.0, vertical_translation=0.0):
           self.frequency = frequency
           self.amplitude = amplitude
           self.phase_shift = phase_shift
           self.vertical_translation = vertical_translation

       def __call__(self, time):
           try:
               amplitude = self.amplitude(time)
           except TypeError:
               amplitude = self.amplitude

           try:
               frequency = self.frequency(time)
           except TypeError:
               frequency = self.frequency

           try:
               phase_shift = self.phase_shift(time)
           except TypeError:
               phase_shift = self.phase_shift

           try:
               vertical_translation = self.vertical_translation(time)
           except TypeError:
               vertical_translation = self.vertical_translation

           return amplitude * sin(2 * pi * frequency * time + phase_shift) + vertical_translation

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       SAMPLE_RATE = 96000
       NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS = 1
       SAMPLE_WIDTH = 4
       MAX_AMPLITUDE = 2 ** (8 * SAMPLE_WIDTH - 1)

       with wave.open('output.wav', 'w') as output:
           output.setsampwidth(SAMPLE_WIDTH)
           output.setnchannels(NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS)
           output.setframerate(SAMPLE_RATE)
           output.setcomptype('NONE', 'Uncompressed')

           a440 = Wave(440)

           for time in range(SAMPLE_RATE // a440.frequency):
               sample = MAX_AMPLITUDE * a440(time / SAMPLE_RATE)
               output.writeframes(struct.pack('l', round(sample)))
   ```

I'd greatly appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce your issue. After running your code I get a perfect sine wave of the expected length (1/440Hz ≈ 0.0023s) when inspecting the .wav in Audacity:

[image: sine wave]

I do have one note for you, you can't simply round whatever comes out of `sin * MAX_AMPLITUDE`. You have to truncate towards negative infinity. This is because a (say) 8-bit sample goes from -128 to 127, not -128 to 128.

Comment: Interesting. I get your output when I change the format from `'l'` to `'d'`. Apparently, long integers on my machine are 8-bytes whereas your machine must use 4-byte wide long integers. Well, shoot. So much for platform-independent code.

Comment: @TylerCrompton That makes no sense, `d` is the double format.

Comment: \*shrug\* I might have looked at the results when I tried `'i'`. Anyway, I fixed it by changing the the form to `'{}s'.format(SAMPLE_WIDTH)` and changing the value to be packed to `sample.to_bytes(SAMPLE_WIDTH, 'little', signed=True)`. Additionally, I couldn't use only `floor` for the rounding because it's possible that the sample would be exactly equal to `MAX_AMPLITUDE`. This is because there is an odd number of possible negative values and an even number of possible positive values when using two's complement. So I used `floor` and clipped any values out of the allowed range. Thanks!